# How to filter an array according another array in object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I have an array:

```
const arr = [
    {id: 1, text: "hello", likes: [1,2,5]},
    {id: 2, text: "text", likes: []},
    {id: 3, text: "example", likes: [1]}
]
```

how to filter it according to the length of likes array i.e array should be like this:

```
const arr = [
        {id: 1, text: "hello", likes: [1,2,5]},
        {id: 3, text: "example", likes: [1]},
        {id: 2, text: "text", likes: []},
    ]
```

Comment: The method you're looking for is [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), not `filter`.

Comment: Use `Array.sort()`: arr.sort((a, b) => b.likes.length - a.likes.length)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Array.prototype.sort()` with parameters `a,b` and compare the length property of the `likes` property

**READ MORE HERE**:
[javascript Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```js
const arr = [
    {id: 1, text: "hello", likes: [1,2,5]},
    {id: 2, text: "text", likes: []},
    {id: 3, text: "example", likes: [1]}
]

arr.sort(function(a,b) { 
   return b.likes.length - a.likes.length;
});

for(let a = 0; a < arr.length; a++){
  console.log(arr[a]);
}
```